# Equivalent Autohotkey code from this Arduino code

Tags: arduino, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I trying the translate an equivalent of this Arduino digispark code into AutoHotKey code.

```
DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_Q, MOD_CONTROL_LEFT | MOD_SHIFT_LEFT);
```

This code simply emulated a keyboard and types "CTRL+SHIFT+Q".

I also need a simple AHK code snippet that can detect CTRL+SHIFT+Q" being typed on the main keyboard.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will display a message box when ctrl+shift+Q is pressed.

```
^+q::
MsgBox , ctrl+shift+Q detected
Return
```

If you need it to also fire its native function, place a tilde `~` in front of the hotkey, like this `~^+q::`.

Here's some good info from the help file, [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).